# How to pass an object as a dictionary key in Python(TestComplete issue?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, testcomplete

I am aware dictionary keys needs to be strings or immutable objects. But I don't want to pass strings as a key. Reason is, every where I use the dictionary, I have to type exact string and leaves so mach hard coding and room for errors.

This is only happening on TestComplete (V12).
Is it possible for me to do something like this,

```
class test():
    testStr = 'test'
    testStr2 = 'test2'

class Coverage():
     Data ={test.testStr    : True,
            test.testStr2   : 'something with white space'}
```

If this is a bad idea, why?

Comment: Have you tried it to see what would happen?

Comment: Sure you can. Your key is still a string, just not a string *literal*.

Comment: I tired, I get a Syntax error

Comment: Your code does not produce a Syntax error, in either Python 2 or Python 3. You must have not reproduced it correctly.

Comment: You are right, it is only happening on TestComplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem in TestComplete's Python parser and SmartBear has a patch for it. You can [contact them](http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete) to get the patch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Enum for this purposes.

```
from enum import Enum     # for enum34, or the stdlib version
# from aenum import Enum  # for the aenum version
Animal = Enum('Animal', 'ant bee cat dog')

Animal.ant  # returns <Animal.ant: 1>
Animal['ant']  # returns <Animal.ant: 1> (string lookup)
Animal.ant.name  # returns 'ant' (inverse lookup)
```

or equivalently:

```
class Animal(Enum):
    ant = 1
    bee = 2
    cat = 3
    dog = 4

data = {
    Animal.ant: 'small',
    Animal.dog: 'big'
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, my strings arent always 1 word. Sometimes there are white spaces, thats why I didnt use Enum.